# Video Poker probability

Tags: combinatorics

In video poker the first five cards dealt to me are as follows: 
\begin{pmatrix}
3\heartsuit &6\clubsuit&Q\heartsuit&7\diamondsuit &9\clubsuit
\end{pmatrix} The hand thus contains a single royal flush card. If I keep only the $Q\heartsuit$, discard the rest and draw another four more cards, 
what is the probability of drawing additional royal cards ie any card from any suit of ranks$\begin{pmatrix}10&J&Q&K&A\end{pmatrix}$ such that, the final hand would contain a total of 4 different ranks of the royal?

The possibilities to draw from the remaining $47$ cards would have to include drawing:

a) 3 more in the hearts suit plus 1 non-royal card, or

b)  4 of the 5 royal cards from one of the other 3 suits.

How do you calculate this using combinatorics?

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{pmatrix}3\heartsuit &6\clubsuit&Q\heartsuit&7\diamondsuit &9\clubsuit\end{pmatrix}$

After keeping the queen and discarding the rest, there are 47 remaining cards. The ways to select any 4 more cards (order does not matter) is:

$${47\choose 4} = \;^{47}C_4 = \frac{47!}{4!43!} $$

> a) 3 more royal in the hearts suit plus 1 non-royal card,

There are 3 remaining royal hearts, 32 remaining non-royals of any suit.  The ways to select these are:  ${3\choose 3}\cdot{32\choose 1} = \,^3C_3\cdot^{32}C_1 = 32$

$$\therefore P_A = \frac{\,^3C_3\cdot^{32}C_1}{\,^{47}C_4} = \frac{32\cdot 4!\cdot 43!}{47!}$$

> b) 4 of the 5 royal cards from one of the other 3 suits.

*Assuming that reads: all from the same suit.*

There are 3 other suits.  There are 5 royal cards in each.  Select a suit and then select 4 of the 5 cards in that suit.